# Calculating precentage of a column with bool using two tables

Tags: sql-server

Could somebody please help me create a view in SQL server to get a percentage in  a new column. For example I have two tables as below.

```
Table 1---> Subject          |      Table 2---->Exam
                             |
SubjectID     SubName        |      ExamID   SubjectID   Result (bool)
   1          Science        |        1        1            1
   2          Maths          |        2        1            1
   3          English        |        3        1            0
   4          History        |        4        2            0
   5          Art            |        5        2            1
   6          Geography      |        6        3            0
                             |        7        4            1
                             |
```

As you can see, many subjects do not have exams hence result will be null in a joined view. I want to show the pass percentage of a subject. For example, in result column, 1 = pass, 0 = Fail. I want the result to look like below showing null fields as well.

```
SubjectID    SubName    PassPercentage
    1        Science        66.66
    2        Maths          50
    3        English        0
    4        History        100
    5        Art            null
    6        Geography      null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
SELECT 
Subject.SubjectId, 
Subject.SubName, 
(AVG(CONVERT(decimal,Exam.Result))*100) AS PassPercentage 
FROM Subject
LEFT JOIN Exam on Subject.SubjectId = Exam.SubjectId
GROUP BY Subject.SubjectId, Subject.SubName
```

You can round percentage result (2 or without decimals) and add % sign if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
Select *,
(Select Avg(Cast(Result as decimal)) From Exam Where SubjectID=S.SubjectID)*100 as PassPercentage
From Subject as S
```

Result is:

```
SubjectID   SubName         PassPercentage
----------- --------------- ---------------------------------------
1           Science         66.666600
2           Maths           50.000000
3           English         0.000000
4           History         100.000000
5           Art             NULL
6           Geography       NULL

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Subquery will be executed for each row of subject table.

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
select s.SubjectID, s.SubName, 
case COUNT(e.Result) 
    when 0 then null
    else SUM(CAST(e.Result AS INT)) * 100 / (COUNT(s.SubjectID))
end PassPrec

from Subject s
left join Exam e on s.SubjectID = e.SubjectID
group by s.SubjectID, s.SubName
```

there case is to get the null. nulls don't get counted in "count" function.

Comment: Nulls will be counted using count if you use count(*)

Comment: yes, but i don't want to count them. i'm using the fact that the aren't counted so to know that there are no results for the current subject, and so a 'null' value will be asigned to the % column

Comment: I wasn't saying you code was wrong, just raising caution to your last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

you can use code like this

```
;with cte1 as (
select subjectid, sum(result) ResultCount
from exam group by subjectid
), cte2 as (
select e.subjectid, c.ResultCount, count(e.examid) TotalExams from cte1 c 
left join exam e on e.subjectid = c.subjectid
group by e.subjectid, c.ResultCount
) select s.subname, convert(decimal(10,2), (c.ResultCount/convert(decimal(10,2),c.TotalExams)) *100) as Percentage  from  subject s left join cte2 c
on s.subjectid = c.subjectid
```